# how to find the index of the current option in a selected list

Tags: jquery

I have a select box and I want to try and get the index of the current selected option.
I can get the value of this with.

(#mySelectBox).val();

what I'm after is if say val was set by default to the last option which would be option3 I want to get the index of that option.

```
    <div class="selectItems">
        <select id="mySelectBox">
            <option value="0">option1</option>
            <option value="1">option2</option>
            <option value="2">option3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this blog:](http://www.myphpetc.com/2009/03/jquery-select-elements-tips-and-tricks.html)

```
// Get the text of the selected item
alert($("#myselect option:selected").text());

// Get the value of the selected item
alert($("#myselect option:selected").val());

// Get the index of the selected item
alert($("#myselect option").index($("#myselect option:selected")));
```

Or for jQuery >= 1.6:

```
alert($('#myselect').prop('selectedIndex');
```

But what use is the index when you can just get the value or text for the selection? If you specifically want to know if it's first or last, perhaps...

```
alert($('#myselect option:selected').val() === $('#myselect option:first').val());
alert($('#myselect option:selected').val() === $('#myselect option:last').val());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the .selectedIndex property. If you have a change event on the select box, you can do something like this:

```
$('select').change(function() {
   var currentIndex = this.selectedIndex;
});
```

This would return 2 for option 3.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mySelectBox option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -> http://jsfiddle.net/p6Jfb/

script :

```
$("#mySelectBox").change(function() {
    console.log($(this).get(0).selectedIndex); // prints the currently selected index
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  
    $('#mySelectBox').on('change',function(){
        console.log('Selected Value '+$('#mySelectBox option:selected').val())
        
        console.log('Selected Text '+$('#mySelectBox option:selected').text())
        
        console.log('Selected Index '+$('#mySelectBox option:selected').index())
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectItems">
        <select id="mySelectBox">
          <option value="0">select</option>
            <option value="1">option1</option>
            <option value="2">option2</option>
            <option value="3">option3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

try this one.